# Minimize a linear cost function subject to a cubic equality constraint

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

In the framework of a simple load balancing problem, I am facing an optimization problem, but I am not sure if I am handling it in the right way.

Let's say I have a 3D grid of P distinct ressources, arranged over a 3D mesh of size $p_1 p_2 p_3$, and I want to process a 3D workload of size $mnk$, where all quantities are positive, non zero integer : $p_1, p_2, p_3, m, n, k \in \mathbb{N}^*$

The cost of processing all these workload is
\begin{align}
(p_3-1)mn + (p_2-1)mk + (p_1-1)nk
\end{align}

Here, we have $m,n$ and $k$ three constants of the problem, and $p_1, p_2$ $p_3$ variables constrained by $p_1 p_2 p_3 = P$. Finding the best possible grid configuration is then equivalent to solve a constrained optimization problem of the form:

\begin{equation}
  \underset{p_1*p_2*p_3=P, p_1,p_2,p_3 \in \mathbb{N}^*}{argmin} \alpha_1 p_1+ \alpha_2 p_2+\alpha_3p_3
\end{equation}
with $\alpha_1=mn$, $\alpha_2=mk$ and $\alpha_3=nk$

My first idea was to transform the integer variables into real positive constraints. so that I get at least an approximate solution for the integer case, and tranform the product into a sum using a log.
Then I should be able to use the method of lagrangian multiplier ?

\begin{equation}
  \underset{log(p_1)+log(p_2)+log(p_3)=log(P), p_1,p_2,p_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}}{argmin} \alpha_1 p_1+ \alpha_2 p_2+\alpha_3p_3
\end{equation}

Another possibility would be to put $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ in a diagonal matrix, and solve a linear optimization problem with an equality constraint on the matrix determinant, but this does not look easier.

In one of the paper I am reading, the author use a slightly different approach, he claims that load balancing is effective only if every ressource has the same amount of work to do, hence a change of variable of the form:
$n_1=\frac{m}{p_1}, n_2=\frac{n}{p_2}$ and $n_3=\frac{k}{p_3}$, and the constraint $n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P}$, we can setup:

\begin{align}
  &\underset{n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P} \in \mathbb{N}}{argmin} \frac{m}{n_1}nk+ \frac{n}{n_2}mk+ \frac{k}{n_3}mn\\
  \Leftrightarrow &\underset{n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P} \in \mathbb{N}}{argmin} (mnk) \left( \frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\frac{1}{n_3}\right)\\
  \Leftrightarrow &\underset{n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P} \in \mathbb{N}}{argmin} (mnk) \left( \frac{n_2 n_3+n_1 n_3+n_1 n_2}{n_1 n_2 n_3}\right)\\
  \Leftrightarrow &\underset{n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P} \in \mathbb{N}}{argmin} (mnk) \frac{P}{mnk} (n_2 n_3+n_1 n_3+n_1 n_2)\\
  \Leftrightarrow &\underset{n_1 n_2 n_3 = \frac{mnk}{P} \in \mathbb{N}}{argmin} (n_2 n_3+n_1 n_3+n_1 n_2)
\end{align}

This problem is exactly equivalent to the minimum surface cuboid, with a given volume, whose solution in the continuous case is that each ressource should handle a subcube of the total work, then assuming $n_1=n_2=n_3$, which simplifies the problem even further:
\begin{align}
n_1 &= \sqrt[3]{\frac{mnk}{P}}\\
p_1 &= \frac{m}{n_1}\\
p_2 &= \frac{n}{n_1}\\
p_3 &= \frac{k}{n_1}
\end{align}

(Edit) How can I now solve this problem in the integral case

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of $P$?

Comment: Between 8 and 5000 I would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $b, c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb N^+$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + c_3 x_3\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 x_2 x_3 = b\\ & x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb N^+\end{array}$$

Let the prime factorization of $b$ be

$$b = p_1^{m_1} \cdot p_2^{m_2} \cdots p_n^{m_n}$$

where $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ are the $n$ prime factors and $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n$ are their multiplicities. From the prime factorization, one can generate all (finitely many) triples $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ that satisfy the cubic equality constraint. Evaluating the objective function at each triple, one can find the minimum.

---

#### Example #1

Let $b := 12$. Note that $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$. Brute-forcing in Haskell:

```
Prelude> triples = [ (x1,x2,x3) | x1 <- [1..12], x2 <- [1..12], x3 <- [1..12] ]
Prelude> triples' = filter (\(x1,x2,x3)->x1*x2*x3==12) triples
Prelude> triples'
[(1,1,12),(1,2,6),(1,3,4),(1,4,3),(1,6,2),(1,12,1),(2,1,6),(2,2,3),(2,3,2),(2,6,1),(3,1,4),(3,2,2),(3,4,1),(4,1,3),(4,3,1),(6,1,2),(6,2,1),(12,1,1)]
Prelude> length triples'
18
```

Hence, one only has to evaluate the objective function at $18$ triples. One can arrive at the number of solutions without using brute force, however. Let each solution be of the form

$$(2^{\kappa_1} \cdot 3^{\ell_1}, 2^{\kappa_2} \cdot 3^{\ell_2}, 2^{\kappa_3} \cdot 3^{\ell_3})$$

Since the product must be $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$,

$$2^{\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3} \cdot 3^{\ell_1 + \ell_2 + \ell_3} = 2^2 \cdot 3$$

and, thus, one obtains two linear equations over the nonnegative integers

$$\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3 = 2 \qquad \qquad \qquad \ell_1 + \ell_2 + \ell_3 = 1$$

The number of nonnegative integer solutions of the equation $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = k$ is the coefficient of $t^k$ in the following generating function

$$\dfrac{1}{(1-t)^3}$$

Using SymPy:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> f = 1 / (1-t)**3
>>> f.series(t,0,3)
1 + 3*t + 6*t**2 + O(t**3)
```

Thus,

- $\kappa_1 + \kappa_2 + \kappa_3 = 2$ has $6$ nonnegative integer solutions
- $\ell_1 + \ell_2 + \ell_3 = 1$ has $3$ nonnegative integer solutions

Hence, the total number of solutions is $6 \cdot 3 = 18$. Finding all positive integer solutions of the cubic equation $x_1 x_2 x_3 = 12$ thus boils down to finding all nonnegative integer solutions of $n = 2$ linear Diophantine equations, i.e., finding all integer points inside a polytope.

---

#### Example #2

Let $b := 5000 = 2^3 \cdot 5^4$. Using SymPy:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t') 
>>> f = 1 / (1-t)**3
>>> f.series(t,0,5)
1 + 3*t + 6*t**2 + 10*t**3 + 15*t**4 + O(t**5)
```

Hence, the total number of solutions is $10 \cdot 15 = 150$.

---

#### Example #3

Let $b := 5040 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7$. Since $z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 1$ has $3$ nonnegative integer solutions, the total number of solutions is $3^6 = 729$.

Comment: I'll just wait to have a bit more time to read your solution before accepting it, however it seems right, the prime number decomposition tool looks indeed helpful for those kind of problem. Plus you gave some code examples, which is great. However I am a bit disappointed that we cannot use the solution of the continuous problem to discard some parts of the solution tree in a branch and bound manner. Do you know if that would be possible ?

Comment: @Tobbey I added two more examples. Note that even if $b$ is relatively large, the search space is not that big. Brute force can still be used, though it is not pretty.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: @Tobbey Relaxing the integrality constraints, one has a [geometric program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_programming).